# a error occur in remoteDriver function of RSelenium

Tags: rselenium

I want to scrape data on dynamic web by the following code:

```
> URL<- "http://www.cbooo.cn/realtime"
> library(bitops)
> library(RCurl)
> library(XML)
> library(RSelenium)
> library(magrittr)
> checkForServer()
Warning message:
checkForServer is deprecated.
Users in future can find the function in file.path(find.package("RSelenium"), "example/serverUtils").
The sourcing/starting of a Selenium Server is a users responsiblity. 
Options include manually starting a server see vignette("RSelenium-basics", package = "RSelenium")
and running a docker container see  vignette("RSelenium-docker", package = "RSelenium") 
> startServer()
$stop
function () 
{
    tools::pskill(selPID)
}
<environment: 0x10991af0>

$getPID
function () 
{
    return(selPID)
}
<environment: 0x10991af0>

Warning message:
startServer is deprecated.
Users in future can find the function in file.path(find.package("RSelenium"), "example/serverUtils").
The sourcing/starting of a Selenium Server is a users responsiblity. 
Options include manually starting a server see vignette("RSelenium-basics", package = "RSelenium")
and running a docker container see  vignette("RSelenium-docker", package = "RSelenium") 
> remDrv <- remoteDriver()
> remDrv$browserName="Internet Explorer"
> remDrv$open()
[1] "Connecting to remote server"

Selenium message: The best matching driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver can't create a new driver instance for Capabilities [{nativeEvents=true, browserName=Internet Explorer, javascriptEnabled=true, version=, platform=ANY}]
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-J0D980N', ip: '10.36.17.76', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown 
Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

There are the following questions which I can't solve:
 1 checkForServer,startServer are deprecated.
 2 connecting to remote server always fials,I don't konw how to set some argurment in this funciotn and what should be done
I hope to get a anwser as soon as possible ,thanks.

Comment: Do you have internet explorer or edge installed? If you have edge you would call like `remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "MicrosoftEdge")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to produce a viable working solution I would use the old version of RSelenium and everything with this code.

```
if (!require("XML")) {
  install.packages("XML",repos= 'https://cloud.r-project.org') 
  library("XML")
}
#XML is a dependency
if (!require("RSelenium")) {
  install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RSelenium/RSelenium_1.3.5.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source", dependencies = TRUE)
  library("RSelenium")
}
download.file('http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.53/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar', destfile = "~/Documents/R/library/RSelenium/bin/selenium-server-standalone.jar")

#start server
system('java -jar "~/Documents/R/library/RSelenium/bin/selenium-server-standalone.jar"')

library(RSelenium)
checkForServer()
startServer()
```

That is not an optimal solution. But a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

The author of RSelenium provides a solution as following (https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/81):

From Firefox 48 on-wards the gecko driver/ marionette will be needed to run Firefox with Selenium.

If you have Firefox 48 you can run the gecko driver as follows:

Refer to the guidelines

https: //developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver

Download the relevant gecko driver from 
https: //github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Add it to your PATH or refer to the location when starting binary (see below)

```
# get beta selenium standalone
RSelenium::checkForServer(beta = TRUE)
# assume gecko driver is not in our path (assume windows and we downloaded to docs folder)
# if the driver is in your PATH the javaargs call is not needed
selServ <- RSelenium::startServer(javaargs = c("-    Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=\"C:/Users/john/Documents/geckodriver.exe\""))
remDr <- remoteDriver(extraCapabilities = list(marionette = TRUE))
remDr$open()
....
....
remDr$close()
selServ$stop()
```

Comment: I have used the above solution provided by @Tien Lin and it has worked. I have put the geckodriver in my user folder and added the path to it in the system variables. I use Windows 10. The following is how I used it:

    `selServ <- startServer()
     remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost" 
                      , port = 4444
                      , browserName = "firefox"
                      , extraCapabilities = list(marionette = TRUE))`.

Then the obvious `remDr$open` and `remDr$navigate(toURL)`. My mistake was to upgrade versions...